# std::ofstream.write - синхронная или асинхронная?

Tags: c++, файлы, асинхронность, fstream

Использую в программе запись через поток довольно большого объема данных (6ГБ)

```
std::ofstream file(path, std::ios::binary);
file.write(buffer, size);
file.close();
```

Когда смотрел как появился файл на диске и какой размер он имел (при том, что программа отчитывалась, что она продолжает работать дальше), то у меня сложилось впечатление, что запись на диск работала **асинхронно**

Успокойте меня и скажите, что приведенный код работает синхронно, т.е. последовательно, а то у меня иначе получается запись в буфер и сохранение буфера идет одновременно, то полностью разрушает данные.

Comment: После вызова `write` буфер точно можно удалять, а после вызова `close` в файле должны появиться все данные. Я так понимаю, сам write может быть и асинхронным, но тогда он обязан сразу копировать себе содержимое переданного буфера. А close обязан делать flush.

Comment: *Успокойте меня и скажите, что приведенный код работает синхронно*. Успокойтесь, приведенный код работает синхронно :)